# Is there a sane way to simulate virtual inheritance in Django models?

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I want to log actions made by users. In most OO languages, I would implement this via a `LoggedAction` class, having several child classes like `LoginAction`and `LogoutAction`. I could then iterate over a list of  `LoggedAction`s and get the specific child behaviour through virtual inheritance. This does not work using Django models however.

Example `models.py`:

```
class LoggedAction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s %s" % (unicode(self.timestamp), unicode(self.user), unicode(self.action()))

    def action(self):
        return ""

class LoginAction(LoggedAction):
    def action(self):
        return "logged in"

class LogoutAction(LoggedAction):
    def action(self):
        return "logged out"
```

Then I'd like to do `[unicode(l) for l in LoggedAction.objects.all()]` and get a list of messages like `u'2012-02-18 18:47:09.105840: knatten logged in'`.

As expected, this does not work, since what I get from `all()` is a list of `LoggedAction` objects having either a `loginaction` member or a `logoutaction` member. (The output is a list of messages like `u'2012-02-18 18:47:09.105840: knatten`, with no mention of the action.)

Is there a *sane* way to get the behaviour I'm after, or am I trying to apply the wrong paradigm here? (I guess I am, and that I should just have the specific action as a member in `LoggedAction`)

Comment: Realise that as you have shown it here it will be implemented in the database as three tables, with LoginAction and LogoutAction joining on a common table, and LoggedAction objects can be instantiated. You may want to make LoggedAction abstract.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan If I make `LoggedAction` abstract, I wont be able to iterate over them, am I right? So in particular `LoggedAction.objects.all()` will be impossible?

Comment: Not sure; as a matter of fact I've never had cause to iterate over a model with subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is probably the wrong paradigm. It's easy to be misled by the object-relational mapper (ORM) - database tables don't really map all that well to objects, and this difference is known as the [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

What you actually need is to make `action` a field. This field can take a `choices` parameter which represents the possible values of that field - ie logged in or logged out:

```
class LoggedAction(models.Model):
    ACTIONS = (
       ('I', 'logged in'),
       ('O', 'logged out')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIONS)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s: %s %s" % (self.timestamp, self.user, self.get_action_display())
```

Note that I've used arbitrary single-character strings to represent the actions, and the `get_action_display()` magic method to get the full description.

Comment: Yeah, it is probably a bit optimistic to expect being able to slap full OO on top of a relational database.
I want to be able to store some extra information in the subclasses, but they will probably all be a `TextField`. So I guess I can go with your solution, having that `TextField` in the `LoggedAction` class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`InheritanceManager`](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/overview#inheritancemanager) from django-model-utils. It allows you to get the concrete subclasses.